# Reverse-migrating questions from other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, migration, stackexchange

Searching through the Stack Exchange network for tags like [raid](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/raid), [mdadm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mdadm) or whatever, I've found quite a few questions (mainly pre-2010) that seem like they belong on Server Fault; should we (aggressively or otherwise) be flagging these for migration, or leaving them as is?

Comment: Pre-2010? I'd say bin 'em. If the OPs are still awaiting an answer, well, they can re-port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I've seen of other questions migrated lately, despite the best of intentions, I can only ask that you don't do it. Very few of them have been even half decent questions and because many (most?) of the posters don't follow the question after the migration the almost obligatory prompts for more (or even relevant) information are to no avail, making the questions less than beneficial to the site.

If questions are individually examined, rather than a cursory glance at the question and tags, some may be worth migrating but most will more than likely be candidates for closure. After all, a person who asks on the wrong site (at least since SF and SU were born) is unlikely to post a decent question in the first place.

Comment: the guidance is a) don't migrate crap, ever and b) for old questions, only migrate the *best* and most *on-topic* ones for the target site.

Answer (score 1):

Your perogative really. If you want to flag them on the other sites as "belongs on SF", then it's up to the mods of the other sites to decide if they want to move them.

Generally we tend to avoid migrating old questions (say, 12 months or older), or questions that are just crappy questions that would likely be closed on SF once they're migrated.